# Text out of view in Touchable opacity React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react native and i'm trying to display some text in a custom touchable opacity. but the text keep exceeding the border even when i'm using flex wrap. my code is the following:

```
 <View style={styles.main_container}  >
       <View style={styles.ctr1}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
                       <Image style={styles.img} source={{ uri:`data:image/gif;base64,${encodedData}`}}/>

                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.txt}> k </Text>
                            <Text style={{ flexWrap:1 }} > ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd </Text>
                            <Text> kk </Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
</View>
```

and here is look of the styles i used:

```
main_container: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 300,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: "grey",
        width: '95%',
        margin: 10,
    },
ctr1: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        //margin: 2,
    },
```

How can i wrap it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was not in the `<Text>` element that you have given the style `flexWrap:1`. Problem was in the parent elements.

Adding `flex: 1` to `<TouchableOpacity>` and `<View>` which contains your `<text>` will solve the problem.

This will do the calculation for width depends on the device width.

```
<View style={styEdit.main_container}>
            <View style={styEdit.ctr1}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }} >

                    <Image style={styles.img} source={{ uri:`data:image/gif;base64,${encodedData}`}}/>

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1 }}>
                        <Text style={styEdit.txt}>k</Text>
                        <Text>ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd---</Text>
                        <Text>kk</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
```

---

[image]

Tested the code in my machine.
Cheers!

Comment: i did it and it worked, thanks a lot! also i found out that my touchable opacity was imported from 'react-native-gesture-handler' that makes it not function like if you imported it form 'react-native'